# toString() for DoublyLinkedList

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

It's just not working ):
Here's my toString() method.

```
public String toString() {
    String s= "[";
    DoublyLinkedList<E>.ListNode next= new ListNode(null,null,null);
    next= head.successor();

    while(next!=tail){
        s+= next.getValue()+ ", ";
        next=next.successor();

    }
    s +="]";
    // Write this method body and remove this comment
    return s;
}
```

it tells me there's a null pointer error at "next= head.successor()"

Here's the class ListNode:

```
 /** An instance is a node of this list. */
public class ListNode {
    /** Predecessor of this node on the list (null if the list is empty). */
    private ListNode pred;

    /** The value of this node. */
    private E value; 

    /** Successor of this node on the list. (null if the list is empty). */
    private ListNode succ; 

    /** Constructor: an instance with predecessor p (p can be null),
     * successor s (s can be null), and value v. */
    private ListNode(ListNode p, ListNode s, E v) {
        pred= p;
        succ= s;
        value= v;
    }

    /** Return the value of this node. */
    public E getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /** Return the predecessor of this node in the list (null if this node
     *  is the first node of this list). */
    public ListNode predecessor() {
        return pred;
    }

    /** Return the successor of this node in the list (null if this node
     *  is the last node of this list). */
    public ListNode successor() {
        return succ;
    }
```

And DoublyLinkedList...

```
    /** An instance is a doubly linked list. */
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> {
    private ListNode head; // first node of linked list (null if none)
    private ListNode tail; // last node of linked list (null if none)

    private int size; // Number of values in linked list.

    /** Constructor: an empty linked list. */
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
    }

    /** Return the number of values in this list. */
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    /** Return the first node of the list (null if the list is empty). */
    public ListNode getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    /** Return the last node of the list (null if the list is empty). */
    public ListNode getTail() {
        return tail;
    }

    /** Return the value of node e of this list.
     * Precondition: e must be a node of this list; it may not be null. */
    public E valueOf(ListNode e) {
        return e.value;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `Iterable` for your list.

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<E> implements Iterable<E> {
    ...

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
       // TODO: return a new iterator here.
    }
}
```

Then implement an `Iterator<E>` for your list as an inner class.  See Java source code for examples:

- [`java.util.AbstractList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.Itr)
- [`java.util.LinkedList` `ListItr`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.ListItr)

It is a well-established pattern for iterating through lists.  Then, you don't have to worry about getting your `while` loop right, instead, you can just use standard `for` each loops:

```
for (E item: this) {

}
```